# How can I get an image file from my firebase storage

Tags: image, firebase, react-native, download, firebase-storage

I would like to get an image from my firebase storage.
The path is: images/recipes/test.jpg and I want to make it while getting the other data from a specific path of my collection.

Here is the whole code:

```js
_retrieveData = async() => {
      let fbData = [];
      let getImageURL = '';

      await Firebase.db.collection('fl_content').get().then(query => {
        query.forEach(doc => {

          firebase.files.ref().child("images/recipes/test.jpg")
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => {
            getImageURL = url;
          });

          fbData.push({
            id: doc.id,
            titel: doc.data().titel,
            beschreibung: doc.data().beschreibung,
            bild: getImageURL
          });
        })
      });

      this.setState({ fbData, isLoading: false });
    }
```

I see a never ending ActivityIndicator :(.
Without the "firebase.files" section (until the beginning of fbData.push), I get the id, titel and beschreibung from my collection.

Does anybody know, how can I get the direct image? After that I would like to get the image, which is noticed as a reference in the collection. But first it would be great to get the image directly.

The authentication parts are public for the first step!

Comment: It looks like you're not dealing with promises correctly.  getDownloadURL is asynchronous and returns immediately.  It's also confusing that you're mixing async/await and then callbacks in the same bit of code.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you have a solution to share.

Comment: yes its done. Can I close this thread anywhere?

Comment: You can accept your own answer as correct (after the time limit expires), and it will be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes thanks! I got it right now. Here is my code:

```
_retrieveData = async() => {
      let fbData = [];

      await Firebase.db.collection('recipes').get().then(query => {
        query.forEach(doc => {
          Firebase.storage.ref(doc.data().teaser).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            fbData.push({
              id: doc.id,
              titel: doc.data().titel,
              teaser: url
            });
            this.setState({ fbData, isLoading: false });
          });
        })
      });
    }
```